# Where to add an if statement inside for foreach loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a CSV file like this:

```
1,01/01/2001,hello
2,19/09/2013,world
3,12/05/2016,world
4,13/05/2016,hello
5,12/12/2012,world
6,05/02/2006,world
7,06/03/2011,hello
```

I have this set of [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37185477/6234613) from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185038/linq-unable-to-orderby-date-in-specific-column) I asked yesterday:

```
string parts = new StringReader(@"C:\input.txt").ReadToEnd();
string[] lines = parts.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
List<string> dates = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    string[] data = lines[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    dates.Add(data[1]);
}

var datesSorted = dates.OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd/MM/yyyy", null));

foreach (string s in datesSorted)
{
    sb.AppendLine(s + "<br />");
}

Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

The above code works just fine but now I have another problem. I want to add an `if` statement within the code to only display the chosen value's date and all I could think of is doing either something like this:

```
string parts = new StringReader(@"C:\input.txt").ReadToEnd();
string[] lines = parts.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
List<string> dates = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    string[] data = lines[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    dates.Add(data[1]);
    var datesSorted = dates.OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd/MM/yyyy", null));

    if (data[2] == "hello")
    {
        foreach (string s in datesSorted)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(s + "<br />");
        }

        Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Or placing the `if` statement within the `foreach` loop, which results in the same output:

```
01/01/2001
01/01/2001
19/09/2013
12/05/2016
13/05/2016
01/01/2001
05/02/2006
06/03/2011
12/12/2012
19/09/2013
12/05/2016
13/05/2016
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things you may want to consider doing instead is to use an intermediate class to represent a csv line, e.g.

```
private class CSVEntry
{
    public int EntryNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And then change your data loading to:

```
List<CSVEntry> csvlist = new List<CSVEntry>();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    string[] data = lines[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    csvlist.Add(new CSVEntry() { EntryNo = Int32.Parse(data[0]), Date = DateTime.ParseExact(data[1], "dd/MM/yyyy", null), Text = data[2] });
}
```

Then chose what to display by doing something like:

```
var results = csvlist.Where(x => x.Text == "hello").OrderBy(x => x.Date);
Label1.Text = String.Join("<br />", results.Select(x => x.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

The benefit to doing it this way is that you can re use what you have loaded in previously, and any changes to display new values can be done in a LINQ projection.

**Edit:**

I suggest you move the 'loading' into a separate function, e.g.

```
public List<CSVEntry> LoadData(string filename, ... other params) {...
```

and then the part where you want to find specific entries

```
public IEnumerable<CSVEntry> FindByName(List<CSVEntry> loadedData, ICollection<string> targetNames)
{
     return loadedData.Where(x => targetNames.Contains(x.Text));
}
```

Moving on, you can call it by passing an array/list to the function

```
var results = FindByName(csvList, new string[] { "hello", "world"});
```

Comment: Hmm. What if I don't have an EntryNo in the real file, but instead I have a `string` of unique identifier?

Comment: In that case you could change the `public int EntryNo { get; set; }` to a `public string EntryId { get; set; }`, and remove the `Int32.Parse...` from the loading section

Comment: I'm getting an error from the `csvlist.Add` line: 'The best overloaded method for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments'.

Comment: Did you change the list's type to `List<CSVEntry> csvlist = new List<CSVEntry>();`? It shouldn't be `List<string>` any more.

Comment: Sorry, my bad for not noticing the `List`. Now, it works great! However, what if I have to find more than one `string` to display? For example, from my CSV example, there is `hello` and `world`, but there is more to that as well. So, how do I extract now?

Comment: My bad for not explaining clearly. What I meant is that the dates of strings are to be displayed separately, not together, in a table. Your updated answer calls more than 1 string and displays the output together, right?

Comment: Why don't you do something like `var helloResults = csvList.Where(x => x.Text == "Hello"); var worldResults = csvList.Where(x => x.Text== "World");` then?

Comment: Right, thanks. I'm really new to LINQ and not familiar with `List<T>` and `IEnumerable<T> `. In fact, it's my first time using all of them. Anyhow, thanks again. I really appreciate you going all out and spoon-feeding me step by step.

Comment: One quick question: How do I `OrderBy` internally, meaning I'm displaying the output as strings sorted according to dates, instead of displaying the dates directly?

Comment: `var results = csvlist.Select(x => x.Text).OrderBy(x => x.Date)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you could make your code much simpler with LINQ.

Try this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\input.txt");

var query =
    from line in lines
    let data = line.Split(',')
    where data[2] == "hello"
    orderby DateTime.ParseExact(data[1], "dd/MM/yyyy", null)
    select data[1];

var dates = query.ToList();

Label1.Text = String.Join("", dates.Select(x => x + "<br />"));
```

This handles the `if` statement you wanted with the `where data[2] == "hello"` in the `query`.

Comment: This is really convenient. I literally have no knowledge about LINQ. Thanks!