# How to Select then OrderBy using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I am trying to sort the contents of a CSV file according to their dates with the following code from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200307/where-to-add-an-if-statement-inside-for-foreach-loop) a posted earlier:

```
private class CSVEntry
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Grp { get; set; }
}

...

List<CSVEntry> csvList = new List<CSVEntry>();

csvList.Add(new CSVEntry() { Date = DateTime.ParseExact(col[7], "dd/MM/yyyy", null), Grp = col[9] });

var results = csvList.OrderBy(x => x.Date); // An error occurs at "Date".

...
```

But I got this error:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found.

What I want the output to be is the strings from other columns but sorted chronologically. When I tried using this code to display the dates:

```
var results = csvList.Where(x => x.Grp == "DEFAULT").OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```

It works perfectly with the output as dates sorted chronologically. However, this time I don't want to display the dates. I want to display the strings from other columns like I've mentioned above. I tried using

```
var results = csvList.Select(x => x.Grp).OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```

but got the same error as well. Where have I gone wrong? I am new to LINQ and unfamiliar with `List<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` and this is my first time using them.

Comment: Just put your Select after OrderBy, not before.

Comment: checkout you csv date format and `DateTime.ParseExact(col[7], "dd/MM/yyyy", null)` date format

Comment: I ran your sample code from above and it worked fine for me, so as Mostafizur says, maybe something is weird about your data? The line with the error is perceiving `x` as a string instead of a CSVEntry as it should be. Can you show us your `using` statements?

Comment: Are you sure the first sample code block is exact? `var results = csvList.OrderBy(x => x.Date);` should not throw an exception since csvList is an IEnumerable<CSVEntry>.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `Select` after your order the records, Like below

```
var results = csvList
    .Where(x => x.Grp == "DEFAULT")
    .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
    .Select(x => x.Grp);
```

Answer (score 6):

Reddy's answer should work, but I will explain it for you, so you understand why it does.

When you use the `Select(x => x.Grp)` Statement you don't have a `IEnumerable<CSVEntry>` anymore. You only have a IEnumerable with all Grp-Entrys from your csvList. So When you try to order them by Date by adding a `OrderBy(x => x.Date)` Statement, Linq doesn't know the Date Property, because in this Statement x is only a string, not a CsvEntry.

In Reddys Answer, he first filter all Entrys by `Grp == "DEFAULT"`. After that he has a `IEnumerable<CsvEntry>` left, so he can Order them by x.Date. After that, again, he has a `IEnumerable<CsvEntry>` left. Only after the last Statement, the `Select(x => x.Grp)` Statement, he has a `IEnumerable<string>` left.

Hope that helps :)